# Just wanted to know all the uses of || operator in javascript

Tags: javascript, logical-operators

I just wanted to know the other uses of `||` operator in javascript rather than just `logical OR` !

Thanks :)

Comment: just search for it :-D, google is your friend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look [Here](http://addyosmani.com/blog/exploring-javascripts-logical-or-operator/), it explains and shows nicely the uses of `||` in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

There is **no** logical `OR` operator in JavaScript syntax. Not sure what you are trying to ask, without the code, but if you say something like:

```
if (trueText || falseText) // Works
if (trueText or falseText) // Doesn't work! Illegal Operator
```

Also check [this](http://addyosmani.com/blog/exploring-javascripts-logical-or-operator/) post, which will help you understand where all you can use `||`.